# Background running app in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, background, desktop

I want to make a background running desktop app using asp.net c#.

The idea is to check a local database table and get all data from that table in order to insert all those data in live database table.

If there is any better solution for that scenario please suggest me one.

Comment: You want to make a background-running application using technology intended for creating websites and web APIs? How does that make sense? I believe you're really looking to create a Windows Service, or an actual desktop application.

Comment: You should start to do some prototyping in order to define your spec's. Start investigating the working of a windowsservice.

Comment: What you are looking for creating windows service project. It doesn't have to be part of ASP.NET. You can run it on any server as long it has the access to the local database and the live database.

Comment: I have data in different local sql server databases and i am looking for store all those data in one database which is on live server and from that i can create api for my web application, can you give me some suggesions about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that what you want to solve is moving data from multiple local databases into a central one so you can consume it via an asp.net website.
I won't be discussing application part since that's an easy problem to solve once you can connect to a db that has all the data you need.

There are several things to consider here:

- Recurrence (one time migration vs continuous synchronization)
- Direction (do you need to sync one-way from local to central or two-way)
- Data Contract (do local databases have same or different schema than central database)

  The Data Contract is your biggest problem if schemas are different since you will need to design at least a target schema for the central database that can take in data from local dbs.
  Even if schemas are identical, you will need to devise a way that data is partitioned in central database, you might need to introduce a sourceDatabaseId column in your tables so you won't have conflicting primary keys (you won't have this problems if your primary keys are guids)

The others can be solved either building:

1. A windows service - Inputs: periodicity (e.g. every hour), source db and target db connection strings. You will have a main loop that waits until time to run has come (based on periodicity) and fetches data from source db and saves them into target db (preferably in batches)
2. A console application - Inputs: source db and target db connection strings. You will just move data in batches. You can configure a Scheduled Task on the server that will perform scheduled runs of your console application to solve the periodic running part.

You would set up one such windows service or scheduled console app per local database.

If you have complex databases you can look into tools like Microsoft Sync Framework to perform this data synchronization.

Comment: Good answer. If the schemas are different, maybe bring SSIS into the mix?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer I don't have complax table structure local and Target schema's are going to be same if you have some examples on that service or schedule console app please suggest me

Comment: quick search yielded [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/console-application-using-windows-scheduler/)

Answer (score 0):

you can develop a windows service to do this type of work and install on server with timer setting.

Comment: can you provide me some example of this, it will help me lot